# optaplanner drools score corruption

Tags: constraints, drools, optaplanner, scoring

I have a simplified drools file with a hard constraint for an over constrained problem; I annotate the planning variable to nullable=true.   The best score is 0hard/0medium/0soft at solving start, local search, and solving ended.  But when I print out the planning entities and their values for the best solution, there are hard constraint violations.  Here is my hard constraint (summarized):

```
when 
    Task (interval!=null, $interval1 : interval, $id : id)
    Task (interval!=null, $interval2 : interval, id > $id, ..., interval.getOverlap($interval1))

then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1 *$interval1.getOverlap($interval2));
```

In more complex rule sets, I have medium constraints that reduce the score for any Tasks with null intervals.

I've read several of the score corruption threads here and believe it's much more likely to be a problem with my implementation rather than an optaplanner/drools bug.  I've tried:

1. Reducing the rules to the one hard constraint
2. Turning on TRACE logging
3. Enabling FULL_ASSERT
4. Benchmarking

And am looking for more troubleshooting ideas.

Problem 2:  I see a lot of not doable moves as in the below.  I do not have any custom moves, and cannot ascertain why these moves are not doable.  The documentation states that the two reasons for non doable moves are 1) no change in solution (clearly not the case per the object ids and that the values I print in toString()) or 2) a move that is impossible--I don't have a custom isDoable so I don't see how that would be the case.

```
2015-11-11 22:48:42,143 [main] TRACE         Move index (0) not doable, ignoring move (...Task@26b1a589@ {132865 3754 3766 20724} <-> ...Task@7b7a17ed@ {44312 27525 27542 19090}).
```

Besides strength and difficulty comparators, then only truly custom code I"m doing is that I return a subset of all possible planning values in the planning entity class value range provider that are specific to that entity.

Using Optaplanner 6.3 / Drools 6.3

I made the planning variable annotation nullable=false, and cannot understand how the best score can be 0/0/0 with two kinds of hard constraints violated.

```
2015-11-13 21:35:17,269 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent (305), best score (uninitialized/0hard/-2795medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (WELL44497B with seed 4409383736).
2015-11-13 21:35:21,458 [main] INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (559), time spent (4496), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft).
2015-11-13 21:35:26,962 [main] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: step total (5106), time spent (10000), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft).
2015-11-13 21:35:26,962 [main] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (10000), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft), average calculate count per second (3271), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
```

I removed ONLY_DOWN from the plan solver configuration and that changes the scoring, but I am still seeing 0 for hard constraints despite some hard constraints occurring in the best solution.  E.g:

```
2015-11-15 13:54:49,058 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent (352), best score (uninitialized/0hard/-1095medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (WELL44497B with seed 4409383736).
2015-11-15 13:55:07,634 [main] INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (219), time spent (18930), best score (0hard/0medium/-5052665soft).
2015-11-15 13:55:18,704 [main] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: step total (5862), time spent (30000), best score (0hard/0medium/-4958070soft).
2015-11-15 13:55:18,704 [main] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (30000), best score (0hard/0medium/-4958070soft), average calculate count per second (11905), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
```

Comment: Perhaps it isn't relevant for answering this in a useful way, but a code snippet should be consistent even if simplified. Where is `$interval2` bound? The result of `interval.getOverlap(...)` cannot be boolean and numeric at the same time, but it is used both ways.

Comment: What type is an interval? Is that type mutable?

Comment: Typo, interval2 is bound in the second when line, I just omitted by accident in question writeup.  It should look like:

        Task (interval!=null, id > $interval2 : interval, $id, ..., interval.getOverlap($interval1))

Comment: Intervals are instances of regular classes and are planning values. They have setters and public access members but I don't change them once solving starts.   The interval member of Task is mutable and accessible via setInterval.  I've tried making it both public and private.

Comment: I tried implementing a custom move and that didn't change the 0/0/0 score at each phase.